# Rendering_response in jsf removes all the data input in h:inputText after ValidatorException

Tags: java, validation, jsf, lifecycle, composite-component

When validating fields before insertions, and adding wrong data in `inputText` fields, 
the validatorexception causes the life-cycle to move to the rendering_response, and the input data is removed from the input text fields or keeping the old data connected to the data set.
using:

```
<h:inputText id="text"
    value="#{cc.attrs.dataSet.data[cc.attrs.field]}"
    validator="#{cc.attrs.dataSet.validate}"
>
```

When using a normal managed bean, the data is kept from the post submit request. Anybody have any ideas why this behavior happens?